# Azure: Java SDK: Queries: The good way to query data?

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL server and an Android App connected to it.

I've been having a lot of problems with the queries. Sometimes it runs like a charm with some requests, but some others will never have any response and thus the app freezes...

I've been trying to do the queries in several forms:

1. The `basic` way:

   mClient.getTable(User.class).execute().get();
2. With a `callback`:

   mClient.getTable(User.class).execute( **CALLBACK HERE** );
3. In a `thread`:

   Runnable r = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {...}
   };
   Thread t = new Thread(r);
   t.start();

Is there any other ways ? Because I can't find out why does the queries work only  one way at some places.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to solve but... you're accessing the database directly from an app on the phone? Meaning, no API? Locally storing db credentials? I realize this isn't an answer, but that's not a very secure approach. As far as your question goes: Asking for "the good way" to query data is very broad and opinion-soliciting, which is off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Azure android SDK. I see what you mean, but the real question (sorry if that was not clear) is: Is there a better way to use the Azure Android SDK ?

Comment: @Dliix Hi, what do you want, such as best practice for using Azure android sdk for mobile service? The offical tutorials and samples are the best practices, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library/ and https://github.com/Azure/mobile-services-samples.